# Finding the particular solution of the 2nd order DE $y''+y=\sin^2x$ by variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The D.E. is:

> $$y''+y=\sin^2x$$

The problem specifies to find a particular solution using solely the variation of parameters method.

By using the double angle identity to rewrite $\sin^2(x)$ as 1/2-1/2cos(2x), then solving for u1* and u2* by Cramer's rule and integrating, my results for u1 and u2 were u1= -cos^3(x)/3, u2= sin^3(x)/3. This gave me a final solution of y=c1cos(x) +c2sin(x) +cos^4(x)/3+sin^4(x)/3.

> However, the solution given by the book is: 
>   $$y = c_1\cos(x) + c_2\sin(x) +\dfrac13\cos^2(x)+ \dfrac13$$

I solved this problem several more times using different identities, and I continue to get the 1st solution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $Y^{(2)}$?

Comment: I've gotten you started with Mathjax. Please read a tutorial to learn how to format for this site.

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as theirs: $-(\cos^4(x)-\sin^4(x))=-(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=-(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))=1-2\cos^2(x)$. Are you sure they don't have a 2 in front of the cosine squared?

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+y=\sin^2 x$$
Now let $y=y_c+y_p$, where $y_c$ is the general solution to
$$y_c''+y_c=0$$
and $y_p$ is a particular solution of
$$y_p''+y_p=\sin^2 x$$
Easily, we may say that
$$y_c=A\cos x+B\sin x$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. Variation of parameters allows us to assume that $y_p$ is in the form
$$y_p=u_1\cos x+u_2\sin x$$
and also tells us that if this is so, then
$$u_1'\cos x+u_2'\sin x=0$$
$$-u_1'\sin x+u_2'\cos x=\sin^2 x$$
By multiplying both sides of the first equation by $\sin x$ and both sides of the second by $\cos x$, we have
$$u_1'\sin x\cos x+u_2'\sin^2 x=0$$
$$-u_1'\sin x\cos x+u_2'\cos^2 x=\sin^2 x\cos x$$
and by adding these equations, we have
$$u_2'(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)=\sin^2 x\cos x$$
$$u_2'=\sin^2 x\cos x$$
and so, since we seek only a *particular* solution, we may let
$$u_2=\frac{\sin^3 x}{3}$$
Now, when we return to our equations to solve for $u_1$, we have
$$u_1'\sin x\cos x+u_2'\sin^2 x=0$$
$$u_1'\sin x\cos x+(\sin^2 x\cos x)\sin^2 x=0$$
$$u_1'+\sin^3 x=0$$
$$u_1'=-\sin^3 x$$
and
$$u_1=\cos x-\frac{\cos^3 x}{3}$$
and so we have
$$y_p=\bigg(\cos x-\frac{\cos^3 x}{3}\bigg)\cos x+\bigg(\frac{\sin^3 x}{3}\bigg)\sin x$$
$$y_p=\cos^2 x-\frac{\cos^4 x}{3}+\frac{\sin^4 x}{3}$$
and, finally,
$$y=A\cos x+B\sin x+\cos^2 x-\frac{\cos^4 x}{3}+\frac{\sin^4 x}{3}$$
$$y=A\cos x+B\sin x+\cos^2 x+\frac{\sin^4 x-\cos^4 x}{3}$$
$$y=A\cos x+B\sin x+\cos^2 x+\frac{\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x}{3}$$
$$y=A\cos x+B\sin x+\frac{\sin^2 x+2\cos^2 x}{3}$$
$$\color{green}{y=A\cos x+B\sin x+\frac{\cos^2 x+1}{3}}$$
Which is the answer given by your book.